# missing ) after argument list. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

multiplayerpiano.com

Can I mix JavaScript and jQuery at once?

```
$(document).on("mousemove".function(evt) {
    if (ebsprite.start = true) {
        ebsprite.stop()}
)}
```

Comment: Swap ')' and '}' at the last line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lot of syntax errors,

```
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(evt) {
//--------------------------^ use comma instead of . to pass parameters
      if(ebsprite.start === true ) { // = is an assignment operator use === instead
        ebsprite.stop()
      }
  });
//^ close your brackets properly here
```

Answer (score 1):

`coma` not a `dote`, and in your condition add one more `=`

```
 $(document).on("mousemove", function(evt) {
  if (ebsprite.start == true) {
    ebsprite.stop()
  }
})
```